# append a django template include with jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

I want to add the following django template include, which is a list item, to a UL called myClass after a jquery post:

```
 $.post(url,data,function(result){
        $( ".myClass" ).append('{% include "mytemplate.html" %}');
        })
```

This results in an error that reloads the page.

I have read about jquery load and it sounds promising.  Either way how do I add the list item?

Comment: An option to do this is that in the `view` you will have return the `template` rendered and append `result` into a `div`

Comment: I did an example of my comment above, see my answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most similar way to do this is that in a `view` you return the `template` already `rendered` for example you have a template named `to_include.html`:

**The template `to_include.html`**

```
<p>{{variable}}</p>
```

**The URL**

```
url(r'^some_view/$', some_view),
```

**The POST request (in the template where you will include `to_include.html`)**

```
 $.post('/some_view/',data,function(result){
        $( ".myClass" ).append(result);
        }, 'html');
```

**The VIEW**

```
def some_view(request):
    variable = "Hi I am an example"
    return render(request, 'to_include.html', {'variable': variable})
```

The logic is that the `view` (`some_view`) will return the `template` (`to_include.html`) already `rendered` to the `POST request`:

```
    <p>Hi I am an example</p>
```

so `result` will be the `template` already `rendered` and :

```
$( ".myClass" ).append(result);
```

really is:

```
$( ".myClass" ).append("<p>Hi I am an example</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to do `$( ".myClass" ).append('{% include "mytemplate.html" %}');`

the one of the possible way is:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="testForm">     
    <input type="text" name="tester" value="">        
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

#### script

```
$("#testForm").on("submit", function(event){    
    $.post('url', $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){
        CreateRow(data);
    }, "json"); 
    event.preventDefault(); 
});

function CreateRow(dd){
    $(".myClass").append(dd.mycontent);
}
```

#### views.py for url

```
import json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def testpost(request):
    str_html="""
    <h1>....</h1>...your full htmlcode
    """       
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"mycontent": str_html}), mimetype="application/json")
```